# inverse of voronoi diagram

Tags: computational-geometry, cgal, voronoi

I work in GIS. I have a set of polygons. I would like to make an algorithm which first check if the polygon set is a valid Voronoi diagram. If yes then returns the set of points which can generate the same voronoi diagram.

Can anybody help me how to go for it

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A short summary of this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47043935/8756717), which uses the term Thiessen polygons instead of Voronoi diagram:

This problem has been solved by [Biedl et al](https://www.sthu.org/research/publications/files/BHH13b.pdf), *Recognizing Straight Skeletons and Voronoi Diagrams and Reconstructing Their Input*, ISVD 2013.

The problem is simpler for some special cases, but not so trivial for general input. Note that for some input there might be infinitely many solutions, i.e., point sets with the same Voronoi diagram:

[image: Many solutions]

The paper by Biedl et al. presents an algorithm that (i) checks whether a polygonal tessellation is a Voronoi diagram and (ii) determines all possible point sets whose Voronoi diagram is equal to the tessellation.

The basic idea is the following: Consider a rooted spanning tree of the dual of the Voronoi diagram and keep propagating local restrictions at Voronoi nodes to a root Voronoi region. The intersection of this restrictions gives all possible solutions.

See more details in the other [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47043935/8756717).